# Chained Select Submit Button STOPPED functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a chained select which allows the user to select the file he/she wish to download according to the academic year >> subjects(according to the year selected) >> the user then clicks "download" to download the linked file found on an external address such as google.

After adding a **script** that "should" transfer the user to the external address all I'm getting is opening a new tab/page for the same page I'm on (similar to a refresh) except the address in the url bar is

```
www..../acyear=firstyear&subj=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&download=Download
```

**SUBMIT BUTTON SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#subj").chained("#acyear");

    $("#download").on("click", function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      $(this).attr('target', '_blank');

      window.open($("#subj").val());

    });

  });
```

This happened after adding the code and script to the **main page** I wanted to have them in , which contains attached **css sheets and jqueries** for certain effects (like slideshows/navbar..)

I also added some **CSS styles** to the **submit button and select tags**, maybe this is the reason?
Not sure where the problem is since it works just fine on a simple html page....

here's the **full code** for the form and script...

```
<form name="monitoring-report" action="" method="get" target="_blank" onsubmit="return validate_form()">                  

      <select name="acyear" id="acyear">

        <option value="">Academic Year</option>

        <option value="firstyear">1st Year</option>

        <option value="secondyear">2nd Year</option>

        <option value="thirdyear">3rd Year</option>

        <option value="fourthyear">4th Year</option>

        <option value="fifthyear">5th Year</option>

      </select>



      <select name="subj" id="subj">

        <option selected >Please select a Subject</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">Select Subject</option>

        <option value="http://www.imejo.co.nf/books.html" class="firstyear">Calculus101</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">Calculus102</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">Physics101</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">Physics102</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">Chemistry101</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">Chemistry102</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">Engineering Workshops </option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">Chemistry102</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">English111</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">English112</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="firstyear">Computer Skills</option>



        <!--second year-->

        <option selected >Please select a Subject</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="secondyear">Select Subject</option>

        <option value="http://www.imejo.co.nf/books.html" class="firstyear">Statics</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="secondyear">Dynamics</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="secondyear">Strength of Materials</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="secondyear">Engineering Drawing B</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="secondyear">Physics Lab</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="secondyear">C++</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="secondyear">Mechanical Drawing </option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="secondyear">Differential Equations</option>

        <option value="http://www.google.com" class="secondyear">Intermediate Analysis</option>


    //same goes for 3rd,4th and 5th year



    <script>

      // Chained - jQuery non AJAX(J) chained selects plugin

      (function($) {

        $.fn.chained = function(parent_selector, options) { 

          return this.each(function() {

            var self   = this;

            var backup = $(self).clone();

            $(parent_selector).each(function() {

              $(this).bind("change", function() {

                $(self).html(backup.html());

                var selected = "";

                $(parent_selector).each(function() {

                  selected += "\\" + $(":selected", this).val();

                });

                selected = selected.substr(1);

                var first = $(parent_selector).first();

                var selected_first = $(":selected", first).val();

                $("option", self).each(function() {

                if (!$(this).hasClass(selected) && !$(this).hasClass(selected_first) && $(this).val() !== "") {

                  $(this).remove();

                }                        

              });

              if (1 == $("option", self).size() && $(self).val() === "") {

                $(self).attr("disabled", "disabled");

              } else {

                $(self).removeAttr("disabled");

              }

              $(self).trigger("change");

            });

            if ( !$("option:selected", this).length ) {

              $("option", this).first().attr("selected", "selected");

            }

            $(this).trigger("change");             

          });

        });

      };

      $.fn.chainedTo = $.fn.chained;

      })(jQuery);



      $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#subj").chained("#acyear");

        $("#download").on("click", function(e){

          e.preventDefault();

          $(this).attr('target', '_blank');

          window.open($("#subj").val());

        });

      });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a JS inspection round apparently I had a corrupt JS file attached ,or at least it had some errors along 
the file is 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

After removing it the script runs perfectly !

PS: JavaScript Console on Google Chrome is wonderful !